# "Install of Apple Watch Application never finished" Error when deploying watch kit app to device

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

So I got my new watch (yay!). I manually added its UDID to the developer portal and refreshed the provisioning profiles and I was able to push an archive to ITC for testing but now I want to run the app in debug on my watch itself.

I try deploying the watch kit app target set to my phone as the device and it sits there and runs/ churns for a while and nothing happens.

If I wait long enough, Xcode eventually errors with

"Install of Apple Watch Application never finished"
[image: Xcode error]

Has anyone run across this or know of any tricks I can try?

Comment: same thing happening for me :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well with much testing and fooling around, I was able to fix the problem.

There was a mix of the error above as well as the usual verification error.

I had to double check and triple check that all 3 of the developer provisioning profiles for watch ext, watch app, and the app were  up to date with the updated Watch UDID device.

Note: For debugging watch apps, I have found that you seem to have to select to run the app from your watch and then the debugger will trigger

Comment: I had this problem as well but all 3 provisioning profiles (phone, ext, app) were all correct.

Anyone else find a solution ?

Comment: Even if you have this problem on Simulator, just change your certificate and PP to default/automatic value and it will work. 8 hrs goes for nothing thx Apple co

Comment: For simulator, had to use PP. For adhoc distribution, changed back to PP to "Automatic".

Comment: DAMN YOU CODE SIGNING

Answer (score 14):

I keep running into this as well with Xcode 7 beta and iOS 9 / watchOS 2 simulators.

One solution that worked for me was to reset and restart both simulators, but it didn't work reliably. So I tried some other things, and what eventually started to work reliably for me was:

1. Go to the "Apple Watch" companion app on the iOS simulator.
2. Click your app's name.
3. Toggle "Show App on Apple Watch" switch as shown in the screenshot below. (turn it off, and back on again)
4. Run the app again from Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with the simulator.  I solved it by resetting both simulators (File/"Reset Content and Settings...").  Not sure if I had to be that drastic... deleting the app may have worked also, restarting the simulator didn't.

Comment: I deleted the app from simulator and reinstall and it works

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but for different reasons when developing with Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

If this helps for anyone developing their WatchKit Extension (not watchOS 2.0 app stand alone) with Xcode 7 beta (and iOS 9) and they wish to test on their actual Watch, I had to make sure the WatchKit App Device Id (on the Apple Dev Portal) AND the Xcode target had App Groups enabled.

This is different. Perviously just the Watch Extension required App Groups enabled.

My WatchKit app DEV provisioning profile also, of course, had to have the UUID of the watch used in development.

Comment: It is important to only answer and just cover the question which is asked, please edit you answer and write down a completely matched and relevant answer

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on a physical device. I fixed this by restart apple watch.

To do this just long press a button on right side of watch and select "Power off" from screen and after that next long press on right side button.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue, and after trying different combinations, I was able to resolve this issue.

Below is list of items you need to check before you debug your Watch App on Simulator:

1. Make sure that the Bundle Identifier of your WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension is set properly and you have selected proper provisioning profile and certificates for both.
2. The Bundle Identifier of your 'WatchKit extension' should contain the Bundle identifier of your 'WatchKit App'. For example if your 'WatchKit App' has bundle identifier as 'com.example.watchkitapp', then your 'WatchKit Extension's' bundle identifier should be 'com.example.watchkitapp.watchkitextension'
3. Make sure your Watch App & Extension has Version Number same as your iPhone app.

I hope the above steps will help you resolve your issue.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solve it by turning 'Keychain sharing' off in Project->Target->Capabilities.

[image: Keychain sharing is on but should be off]

Comment: I think you have to mark Key Chain Sharing `ON`. It works for me.