# WatchKit App doesn't install on my Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, xcode7

After I upgraded to Xcode 7 I had loads of problems compiling my project, which resulted in a new Storyboard file etc...
When all of the errors and warnings were taken care of I removed the app from the phone and did a clean build. The phone app runs fine on the phone and simulator but the WatchKit app only runs in the simulator and doesn't even show up in the phones Watch app. I don't get any warnings or errors. I've spent 2 days searching the net for a possible answer. I have checked both crash logs and the debug log and nothing. I've followed [Can't install WatchKit app on Apple Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881528/cant-install-watchkit-app-on-apple-watch) thread with no luck.

Anyone having any tips?

Best regards,
Frederik

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32602461/3242031

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak, how do you mean “move framework to watch extension"? What files are you moving?

Comment: Do you use this one? http://i.stack.imgur.com/mYrgY.png If not then my comment is not useful for you.

Comment: Nope, that was not the case I'm afraid, but thank's for the try.

Answer (score 0):

Since the WatchKit app was targeting watchOS 2.0 it didn't show up on the iPhones Watch app until I updated the watch to watchOS 2.0. When the watch was updated from 1.0.1 to 2.0, my WatchKit app was automatically installed.

/Frederik